# CSS Grid: repeat + auto-fit + minmax: how to balance row items count to fill the empty space?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm displaying a grid of dynamic boxes.

I'm using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));` to automatically spawn them as columns of the grid.

[image: Current solution]

It works just fine, but, as you can see in the example, the last row has only two items.
Is there any way to tell the browser to try to balance the items count in a row **without excplicity specifying the number of columns** (to preserve responsiveness)?

In the example above, the items count divides perfectly by 4, so it would be reasonable for the grid to have 4 columns, not 5:

[image: Desired effect]

https://codepen.io/poveu/pen/mdoxZjB

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: we can manually cover a few cases but you need to give us those cases. It's easy for 12 elements but how you want it to behave for another counting? and how many elements will you have?

Comment: That's the trick, I don't know how many items there will be in any scenario.
I thought that maybe there is some property that will handle this automatically, like `text-wrap: balance` but for grid items.

Comment: For this to be a soluable problem there needs to be a bit more detail on the constraints. If the viewport is wide enough to take all the squares then is there to be just one row? Or are you aiming for 'as close to a square as you can get' for the shape of the overall grid?

Comment: I mean something like "fill as much as possible but try to balance every row" - so if all the squares fit into one row, then display them on one row. However, if one square doesn't fit and it would cause this one to create a new row, then try to distribute all the items evenly in two rows. And of course this should work for indefinite number of items. But as far as I know, there's no such thing in CSS grid out of the box.